# Dose escalation with peak - which statistical method is appropriate

Tags: mixed-model, methodology

I have a study with 60 patients receiving specific drug. They need to achieve max value of heart rate and as soon as they achieve max, the medication stops. Therefore, I have patients with dose 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 units of drug. All patients achieves max above 30 units of drug. But some has to extend dosing to 40 and 50. Mix model assumption is missing at random. But in my experiment, patients who achieved max at 30 are missing at 40 and 50. Is LMM appropriate and if not, which model would you recommend for this kind of experiment.

Comment: And the purpose of your analysis is ... ?

Comment: Please explain your research question(s)

Comment: The purpose of the analysis is to test the significant differences between baseline, 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 units of drug, regarding the pulse. Hypothesis is that elevating the dose of drug significantly elevates the pulse till some limit. The problem is some patients achieves max at 30 units of drug. Therefore, we have 60 patients on baseline, 10, 20 and 30 units of drug, and on 40 units remains 45 patients and on 50 units of drug remains 35 patients. Is LMM appropriate model to test the sig. diff of pulse between these drug dosage levels?